# Extra metadata for media items

Tags: media

I've made a plugin that allows me to create thumbnails in the media library grabbed from youtube based on a code. Ideally I would store the code as metadata with the media library item. However, I couldn't find out how to do that so I've stored it as metadata associated with the post. However, this doesn't get outputted in the admin when I view the thumbnail in the media library. Is there anyway to modify the output to include my custom post media (video code).

Comment: That sounds very similar to what WordPress does with attachments, but your description is minimal and your code is not posted at all.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-attachments--wp-31100 looks like what I'm looking for

Comment: Post you solution when you get one, please, for the sake of those coming behind you with similar problems.